# TextBox options in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

In my WPF application I have textbox that I should insert a big text in it then show that big text in a preview page. My questions about textbox are:

- How to make writing in textbox doesn't go forwards in horizontal direction and show horizontal scrollbar? i.e. I want text to be written in vertical way without exceeding the width of textbox.
- It's a big text in textbox, so when I show that big text in preview page can I show that big text as paragraphs?
- How can I make headlines for each paragraph? should these headlines written separately in other textboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a RichTextBox. It's Document property is a FlowDocument where you can add also paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Textbox.TextWrapping property. Set it to TextWrapping.Wrap.

```
textBox1.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
```

Comment: TextWrapping property allow u to separate your text into paragraphs ..but will my text appear in preview page as i devided it in textbox??